# Prove $\int_2^\infty{\frac{\ln(t)}{t^{3/2}}},\mathrm{d}t$ converges

Tags: integration

Show, using a comparison test, that $\displaystyle \int_2^\infty{\frac{\log{t}}{t^{\frac32}}}\mathrm{d}t$ converges.

All the answers I've tried shows it diverges, taking $\log{t} \le t^{1/2}$ and $\log{t} \le t$.

Cheers

Comment: Show us one of those answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solving $\log t = t^{1/4}$ we get $t_1=4.177, t_2=5503.66$ from [W|A](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5BLog%5Bt%5D%20==%20t%5E%281/4%29,%20t%5D).

Differentiating $(\log t)' = \frac{1}{x}$ and $(t^{1/4})' = \frac 1 4 t^{-3/4}$. And  $t>t^{3/4}\implies 1/t<t^{-3/4}$.

for $t \ge t_2$, $\log t \le t^{1/4}$.

$$\int_2^\infty \frac{\log t}{t^{3/2}}dt = \int_2^{t_2} \frac{\log t}{t^{3/2}}dt + \int_{t_2}^\infty \frac{\log t}{t^{3/2}}dt \le \int_2^{t_2} \frac{\log t}{t^{3/2}}dt + \int_{t_2}^\infty \frac{t^{1/4}}{t^{3/2}}dt$$.

We know that $\displaystyle \int_{t_2}^\infty \frac{t^{1/4}}{t^{3/2}}dt$ converges. So the integral converges by comparison.

Integrating by parts::
$$\int_2^\infty \frac{\log x}{x^{3/2}}dx = -\frac{2 \log x}{\sqrt x} \big |_2^\infty - \int_2^{\infty} \frac 1 x \frac{-2}{\sqrt x}dx = \sqrt 2 \log 2  + 2 \sqrt 2 $$

Comment: Why do you need all that rigmarole about a comparison test? If we're evaluating it, just do it all the way, it's not hard. Then take a limit.

Comment: And that way you don't have to use Wolfram, the calculus student's succubus

Comment: @leeabarnett yes I see your point, since it is asked to show using comparison test, I showed it ... but can't find nice way for nice expression of $t_2$.

Comment: Oh I didn't see that about having to use comparison tests. I think there must be a better way then.

Comment: @leeabarnett i am hoping so ${{}}$. Well it was my try :((